# How to use Byebug with Sidekiq and Foreman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, foreman, byebug

I have a rails application in which I use foreman to start my rails and sidekiq servers. Since foreman doesn't interact well with regular byebug (you can't see the prompt as you type), I have set up remote debugging for both my rails and sidekiq servers. This works perfectly for the rails server, but when I connect to the byebug server for the sidekiq server, I get the following:

```
$ bundle exec byebug -R localhost:58501
Connecting to byebug server localhost:58501...
Connected.
(byebug:ctrl)
```

And I'm unable to catch any byebug breakpoints.

According to the documentation, the (byebug:ctrl) prompt means that the program has terminated normally (https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug/blob/master/GUIDE.md), but sidekiq is running jobs just fine.

Is there something incorrect in my configuration, or is sidekiq just not compatible with byebug's remote debugging?

**Procfile:**

```
sidekiq: bundle exec sidekiq
rails: rails server
```

**config/initializers/byebug.rb:**

```
if Rails.env.development?
  require 'byebug'

  def find_available_port
    server = TCPServer.new(nil, 0)
    server.addr[1]
  ensure
    server.close if server
  end

  port = find_available_port

  puts "Starting remote debugger..."
  Byebug.start_server 'localhost', port
  puts "Remote debugger on port #{port}"
end
```

Note that when I don't use remote debugging, byebug functions fine with sidekiq (although in foreman I can't see the prompt as I type).

Also note that I've tried using `Byebug.wait_connection = true` before `Byebug.start_server`, but I have the same issue.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I implemented your solution just to get byebug remote debugging working on the rails server with heroku local, but it slowed my server down to a crawl and heroku local became pretty much unresponsive.  Did you have to deal with this issue at all?

Comment: I would suggest using inline job execution locally, since resque or sidekiq are big development overhead. But this is not really an answer, just a suggestion

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but it will solve your problem: https://github.com/Mon-Ouie/pry-remote

Answer (score 3):

I've tried to replicate this locally, and with sidekiq 3.3.1 and byebug 9.0.5, it seems to work fine with a minor adjustment to the require:

```
require 'byebug/core'

def find_available_port
  server = TCPServer.new(nil, 0)
  server.addr[1]
ensure
  server.close if server
end

port = find_available_port

puts "Starting remote debugger..."
Byebug.start_server 'localhost', port
puts "Remote debugger on port #{port}"
```

Job:

```
class TestJob
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    byebug
  end
end
```